# Solve (numerically) a second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

can someone help me in solving the following ODE:

$\sqrt y = ax - bx^2 (1-x)^2 + c x^2 (1-x)^2 y''$

$y(0)=0, y(1)=a^2$

The main problem is that boundary conditions directly follow from the equation itself. Also if you know how to correct it with a proper substitution of variables would be very appreciated.

This is an equation that emerges in an exceptionally important question on the verge of Economics and Mathematics (Multi-Armed Bandits).

Comment: A numerical solution does not proceed without a specification  of the parameters(a,b,c,.).

Comment: you can take any, say, a=2, b=2, c = 1

Comment: First of all, note that this is a non-linear ode so it will not be easy. My question is, do you just need to solve this or do you have to implement the method yourself too?

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas, basically I just want to be able to draw a picture of the solution to this equation for any a,b,c.

Comment: Have you tried chebfun (https://www.chebfun.org/)? If you need help, I can get something running tonight.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas, I don't even know what it is. I tried basic Maple commands and they didn't work for it. Also after introducing a new variable $z=\ln(\frac{x}{1-x})$ you can get rid of $x^2 (1-x)^2$ coefficient at a cost of changing the interval from $[0,1]$ to $(-\infty, +\infty)$. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1):

So I wrote some MATLAB code (You can also run it with Octave). I would prefer to use Chebfun but it sometimes causes problems with Octave and you might not have MATLAB. Here it goes

```
h = 0.001; x = 0:h:1;
a=2; b=2; c=1;
y = zeros(size(x));
y(1) = 0; y(end) = a^2;

objfun = @(x,y) (a*x(2:end-1) - ...
                b*x(2:end-1).^2.*(1-x(2:end-1)).^2 + ...
                c*x(2:end-1).^2.*(1-x(2:end-1)).^2.*(y(1:end-2) - 2*y(2:end-1) + y(3:end))./h^2)).^2;
ynew = y;
for i=1:50
  ynew(2:end-1) = objfun(x,y);
  norm(y-ynew)
  y = ynew;
endfor

plot(x,y)
```

Explanation:

First, I am approximating $y^{\prime\prime}(x) = (y(x-h)-2y(x)+y(x+h))/h^2$.

Second, I am considering the problem as a fixed point problem, i.e. find $y(x)$ such that $$\sqrt{y(x)} = ax - bx^2 (1-x)^2 + c x^2 (1-x)^2 (y(x-h)-2y(x)+y(x+h))/h^2.$$ Further, I am writing it as $$y(x) = (ax - bx^2 (1-x)^2 + c x^2 (1-x)^2 (y(x-h)-2y(x)+y(x+h))/h^2)^2.$$

Then I am using Picard iterations (that is the for loop). I am iterating a fixed number of steps but the difference between consecutive iterates is going to zero.

HOWEVER, I haven't analyzed the method! It may not be convergent, so be careful and check the result to see if it makes sense. I also haven't tested it thoroughly. Let me know if you have further questions, or if you encounter any problems.

Comment: A similarly easy but more stable method would be to reframe this as a root finding problem and use Newton's method

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas, Thank you for a try. Unluckily, Picard iterations do not work here (you can do them even not approximating y'', but just starting with $y(x)=a^2 x^2$ say, and iterating it), it explodes, I've tried it before of course.

Comment: @whpowell96, how do you reformulate a problem of solving an ODE into a root-finding problem?

Comment: That is similar to what I did! I am writing $\sqrt{y^{new}(x)} = ax - bx^2 (1-x)^2 + c x^2 (1-x)^2 (y^{old}(x-h)-2y^{old}(x)+y^{old}(x+h))/h^2$, so it becomes a fixed point problem. You can stop, for example, when $||y^{new}(x)-y^{old}(x)||_2<\varepsilon$. Similarly, you can write it as $0 = \sqrt{y^{new}(x)} -( ax - bx^2 (1-x)^2 + c x^2 (1-x)^2 (y^{new}(x-h)-2y^{new}(x)+y^{new}(x+h))/h^2 )$ and apply Newton's method. Of course, remember that the variable of interest here is $y$!

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas, so basically it is the same... as said, y(x) explodes in this example just around $x = 5*h$. As I remember Picard iterations method works only when the RHS is Lipschitz continuous to have a contraction. Here it's not the case.